# how to make a global MySQL connection method in Java

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I'm trying to make a JavaFX application that require connection to MySQL DB and perform username and password checking(Login) and other CRUD application . below is my Java class to connect and check the username and password .however I don't think this is professional every time I need to make sure the user connected to database or perform other CRUD activities I have to create this whole steps...**is there a more professional way to create a global method can be accessed from anywhere so that I can call it to do the database connection for me ?**

```
public void LoginButtonHandler(ActionEvent event){

    user.setUsername(username.getText().trim());
    user.setPassword(password.getText().trim());
    String Username = user.getUsername();
    String Password = user.getPassword();

    try{           
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  // MySQL database connection
        Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/airinvoice?" + "user=root&password=*******");     
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from users where username=? and password=?");
        pst.setString(1, Username); 
        pst.setString(2, Password);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();                        
        if(rs.next())   {
            Date dNow = new Date( );
            System.out.println("logged in with username: "+Username+" "+dNow);

            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Notification");
            alert.setHeaderText("you are logged in successfully");
            alert.setContentText("you are logged in as "+Username);
            alert.show();
        }         
        else{
            System.out.println("error logging in !");
            Alert erroAlert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            erroAlert.setTitle("Notification");
            erroAlert.setHeaderText("login unsuccessful");
            erroAlert.setContentText("check your username or password");
            erroAlert.show();
        }         
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}//end method LoginButtonHandler
```

Comment: you could use Hibernate for same or could create your own pojos and also create your own datasource that will manage connections for you.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati does hibernate work only with web application ? ...in my case I'm using JavaFX hope it work with JavaFX

Comment: hibernate has no dependency on a web application. Remember it's an ORM framework not MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate class which connects to the database for example:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnection {

  static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/yourDatabaseName";
  static final String DB_USER = "root";
  static final String DB_PASSWORD = "";
  Connection connection;

  public DBConnection(){
    connect();
  }

  public void connect(){
    try{
      Class.forName(DRIVER);
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    }catch(SQLException|ClassNotFoundException e){
      System.out.println("ERROR connecting to database!");
      System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
  }

  public ResultSet select(String query){
    try{
      Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
      ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
      return result;
    }catch(SQLException e){
      System.out.println("ERROR while executing select query!");
      System.out.println(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  public int update(String query){
    try{
      Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
      return statement.executeUpdate(query);
    }catch(SQLException e){
      System.out.println("ERROR while executing update query");
      System.out.println(e.toString());
      return -1;
    }
  }

  public int delete(String query){
    try{
      Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
      return statement.executeUpdate(query);
    }catch(SQLException e){
      System.out.println("ERROR while deleting line!");
      System.out.println(e.toString());
      return -1;
    }
  }

  public void close(){
    try{
      connection.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){
      System.out.println("ERROR while closing connections!");
      System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
  }

}
```