# How to use a prepared sql statement in a global DbConnection in java?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

For school I have a Java project with a couple of Maven libraries.

For our db connection I made a "global" connection file, in this file I have some basic select, update and delete methods, you can call these from other files with eg: `select(query).` 
I got this code from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42587131/11870062

Now the problem; we need a prepared statement and how do I implement this while keeping the select method global usable as it is now.

Here is the DbConnection class:

```java
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> Select(String query){

    try{
        Statement statement = this.connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        while (rs.next()){

            ArrayList<Object> row = new ArrayList<Object>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= metaData.getColumnCount(); i++){
                String strColumnName = metaData.getColumnName(i);
                Object columnValue = rs.getObject(i);
                row.add(columnValue);

            }
            result.add(row);
        }
        return result;

    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Well, you could use `connection.prepareStatement(query)` but unless you'd want to set parameters you wouldn't gain much. Also you should note that passing the query from the outside is a security risk. In a school project like this it is ok for simplicity etc. - but _never do this in production_.

Comment: @Thomas how would you program it? other groups are repeating the same code over and over every time they need to make a call to the db. i thought programming  it like this you dont have to repeat yourself every time you make a call to the database. 

If school would allow it I would be using hibernate or a different ORM atm :)

Comment: @seanpaulharsevoort I do agree with @Thomas. For security best practice, the input should be always verified, but apart from this, the method you implemented is a wide open door for SQL injection. You should never have such a "general purpose" query method, but implement the methods which perform just the query you need for. Then, use `PreparedStatement` instead of classic `Statement`, and the method input parameters should be the value to be passed as where conditions.

Comment: @MarcoTizzano could you maybe explain a little bit more? bc i was just keeping KISS in mind, I want to implement the safest solution :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that this code is in the data acces layer, the query is build from other classes and passed as a variable into the DbConnection class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in some comments, your method breaks the Java security guidelines, for a number of reasons, most important ones:

- It doesn't perform and check against the input
- It is a wide open door to SQL injection attack, as it does not control which type of query is performed over the database.

However, if this is just a school work, I can help you with implementing that by using `PreparedStatemnt`.
The idea is that you make the assumption that the invoker knows the number of parameters included in the input query and gives the exact number of values for it.
Based on that, the easiest implementation I can think of is the following one:

```
public ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> performGenericParameterizedQuery(String queryWithParameters, 
    Object ... values) {
    
    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    
    try(PreparedStatement ps = this.connection.preparedStatement(queryWithParameters)) {
        
        for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
            ps.setObject(i+1, values[i]);
        }
        
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

        while (rs.next()){

            Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= metaData.getColumnCount(); i++){
                String strColumnName = metaData.getColumnName(i);
                Object columnValue = rs.getObject(i);
                row.put(columnValue, strColumnName);
            }
            result.add(row);
        }
    
    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

To be honest, I haven't actually compiled or tested that method. but I just wanted to give you the idea of how to "generically" use the `PreparedStatement`. I assumed you have the `connection` instance available in your class (you may have it as Singleton or just prepare in a specific `init` method of your class), plus you should add all the required import.
You can notice that I used a List of Map, instead of the structure you had choosen, which in my opinion is clearer and more appropriated for the purpose.
In addition, as I did, I would always suggest to wrap your statement on a try-with-resource block, so it will automatically gets closed (along with the `ResultSet`) once the execution goes out from the block and there is not going to be any resource leak.

Comment: Thank you! I still wonder wat best practices are when using the JDBC and a 3 tier architecture. Is my code complete dogshit? Or were my intentions wrong?. Again thank you for the code, i will look on how to further it.

Comment: Regarding Security Guidelines, don't worry for now about it, that something you learn when studying for OCP Java 11. It is actually not common to see it around, but that's the way i do things as well. If you are curious enough, you can have a look at that: [Java 11 Security Guidelines](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/seccodeguide.html)

Comment: Regarding the three tier architecture, It's all about implementing a "Repository" layer which just deals with DB, a service layer which utilizes the repository layer and an upper layer (which can be a controller class or business logic class) which holds the instance of the service and uses it. You can find lots of documentation online, for example take a look at that just to start off: [DAO vs Repository Patterns](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dao-vs-repository)